# insert at cursor in react

Tags: javascript, textarea, reactjs

I need to insert text at caret (current cursor position) in the [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/)-controlled textarea (like autocomplete).

For vanilla textarea I used this code:

```
insertAtCursor: function (myField, myValue) {
    // IE
    if (document.selection) {
        myField.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
    } 
    // FF
    else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
        var startPos = myField.selectionStart;  var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
        myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
        + myValue + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    } else {
        myField.value += myValue;
    }
}
```

but it does not work in React. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the node, by doing `this.getDOMNode()`.  Depending on the rest of your code, you might need to find the textarea within that node; or refactor your textarea into its own component and use refs.

```
insertAtCursor: function (myField, myValue) {
    var myField = this.getDOMNode();

    // the rest of your code
}
```

A nicer alternative is to just determine the cursor position, and insert your new string; and store it back in your state.  This is what I'd recommend.

```
var index = getCursorPosition();
this.setState({
  value: this.state.value.slice(0, index) + theNewString + this.state.value.slice(index + 1)
})
```

Comment: Yeah, sounds great, I already did setState in fact, but how to move the caret after inserted text, so that React respects the move afterwards? Like this: AAA|BBB -> AAACCC|BBB

Comment: Hmm... I'm not actually sure about that.

Comment: `var index = $('#idOfTextarea').prop("selectionStart");` to get index of cursor

Comment: For me I needed to remove the "+ 1)" from the end, as it caused it to replace a character instead of just insert in between. ```value: this.state.value.slice(0, index) + theNewString + this.state.value.slice(index)```

Answer (score 4):

In `React 15.6.1` best option is something like that:

```js
class CursorForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    // Custom set cursor on zero text position in input text field
    event.target.selectionStart = 0 
    event.target.selectionEnd = 0

    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </form>
    )  
  }

}
```

You can get full control of cursor position by `event.target.selectionStart` and `event.target.selectionEnd` values without any access to real DOM tree.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Will have to check this out once I get again to React :)

Comment: @wizzard0 i'll be happy if this helps :).