# How can I access current cursor location using npm package react-mentions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, input, selection-api

I'm currently trying to track the event.target.selectionStart and event.target.selectionEnd for a react-mentions component using an onchange handler. How can I get access to selectionStart and selectionEnd of this input?

```
<MentionsInput
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    placeholder={placeholder}
  >
<Mentions/>
<Mentions2/>

handleChange(e){
  console.log(e)//just object with one key: target
  console.log(e.target.value) //returns value
  console.log(e.target) //object with key value pair for "value": [value]
  console.log(e.target.selectionStart) //undefined
  console.log(e.target.selectionEnd) //undefined
}
```

**references:**
https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions
[insert at cursor in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410767/insert-at-cursor-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what you're trying to do is access the *caret* location.

Assuming your application has only one selection at a time, which is almost always the case, you can get it using `window.getSelection()` and reference the `focusOffset` and `focusNode` properties of the result.

I don't know if you can get the anchor/focus offsets directly from the event's target, but I don't think so.

If you want to add some extra safeguarding you can ensure that the `anchorNode` matches the element from the `event.target` - although with fancy things like this with React, sometimes the target of the event will not actually be the element that's currently in the window's selection.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This gave me the information that I needed, and 
In addition, I also found that you could pass a react 'OnSelect' handler to the component,
the first argument (e) could be referenced to pull the selectionstart and selecitonEnd
e.target.selectionStart, e.target.selectionEnd